# Call from view an action from another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In ASP MVC 4, is it possible from a view to call another controller action?

I'm on `http://localhost:57456/Archers` and I would like to call a method from the controller Participe (So should be `http://localhost:xxxxx/Participe/Action`).

This is only applying to this action, so I don't want to redirect every action to this controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Html.Action** inside your view to call child actions

```
<div> @Html.Action("Action","Participate") </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you call your ParticipeController from the first action, and include the controller result into the view Data or the model to return to the view:

```
public class ArchersController {
    public ActionResult Index() {
        // your current code here

        // your custom call
        var result = new ParticipeController().Action("your params here");
        ViewData["ParticipeResult"] = result;

        // return View();
    }
}
```

Maybe though, some responsibility principles could be applied here in order to isolate the Participe call you want to make here into its own class or method.